# Get value in View from ICollection to pass an ActionLink parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hellow!, i'm need to be able to get the `Id` from `Compromisos` in a View of `Gestion`. My needs is to get the `Id` to passess to an ActionLink and go to the View Details of `Compromisos`

```
public class Gestion
{
    //abbreviated to not make the long post 

    public Personales Personales { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Compromisos> Compromisos { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Compromisos
{
    //abbreviated to not make the long post 

    public Personales Personales { get; set; }
    public Gestion Gestion { get; set; }
}
```

Actually i get the `Id` using this

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Gestion)
                {
                    <tr>                            
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Compromisos)
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                }
```

but i want to be able to do this: `@Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "Details", "Compromisos", new { id = item.Compromisos})` but doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is Id part of the Compromisos model?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "Details", "Compromisos", new { id = item.Compromisos.Id}) would be my thought. Make sure Id is part of the model.

Comment: @Waragi yes, the Id is part of Compromisos model. I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting an error. `ICollection<Compromisos> doesn't contains a definition for 'Id'...`

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be iterating the Model.Compromisos model instead of Model.Gestion? Maybe post your whole model.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Compromisos)
                {
                    <tr>                            
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gestion.[Property])
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "Details", "Compromisos", new { id = item.Compromisos.Id})
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Waragi I finally did it.

```
@foreach (var Item in Model.Compromisos)
                            {
                                @if (item.Id == Item.GestionId)
                                {

                                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Compromisos" target="_blank" asp-route-id="@Item.Id">Detalle</a>
                                }

                            }
```

In the controller I added `.Include(c => c.Compromisos)`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var gestion = await _context.Gestion
            .Include(c => c.Compromisos) //before I had included .ThenInclude(c => c.Compromisos)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (gestion == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(gestion);
    }
```